# How to get the minimum and maximum value for every record in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, redhat

I have a file that looks something like this(Assuming it is sorted by using sort command)

> 1234 00:00:01 
>   1234 00:00:02 
>   1234 00:00:03 
>   1235 00:10:00 
>   1235 00:10:12 
>   1235 00:10:15 
>   1236 00:12:01 
>   1236 00:12:05

I want to get the minimum and maximum value for each record, so the output should be something like this.

> 1234 00:00:01 
>   1234 00:00:03 
>   1235 00:10:00 
>   1235 00:10:15 
>   1236 00:12:01 
>   1236 00:12:05

I can achieve this by doing something like sorting first into highest to lowest and getting the first unique values to get the highest, and will sort it again ascending to get the lowest next time, and combine the records, is there any faster way of doing this?

Comment: The file is sorted, such that the first line for a new number in first column is the min and the last is the max?

Comment: it is not yet sorted at first, I just posted it sorted so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!($1 in min){min[$1]=max[$1]=$2} 
         min[$1]>$2{min[$1]=$2} 
         max[$2]<$2{max[$1]=$2} 
                END{for(k in min) {print k,min[k]; print k,max[k]}}' file

1234 00:00:01
1234 00:00:03
1235 00:10:00
1235 00:10:15
1236 00:12:01
1236 00:12:05
```

alternative with `sort`

```
$ (sort -k2 file | sort -uk1,1 && sort -k2r file | sort -uk1,1) | 
  sort

1234 00:00:01
1234 00:00:03
1235 00:10:00
1235 00:10:15
1236 00:12:01
1236 00:12:05
```

or, without the final sort

```
paste -d'\n' <(sort -k2 file | sort -uk1,1) <(sort -k2r file | sort -uk1,1)
```

another alternative with one main sort (two unique sorts, but faster)

```
sort -k2 file | tee >(sort -uk1,1) >(tac | sort -uk1,1) >/dev/null | paste -d'\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer using awk, I'd rather avoid using sort more than 1 time because I'm dealing with large files, and sorting just one time takes more than 30 sec. So I guess I'll just have to make do with the awk, evne though it is less readable for people inexperienced with awk.

Comment: for `awk` no need to sort upfront, you can sort the output which should be much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Using sort, awk and the observation that the previous max and next min occur on change of the key in sorted files:

```
awk 'prevKey != $1 { print prevLine 
                     print $0 
                     prevKey = $1  } 
                   { prevLine = $0 } 
     END           { print $0 }
    ' <( sort -n yourfile )
```

Comment: Nice. Just a note that `print $0` is redundant, and `print` suffices.